# Clarification of Flow Structure of Laravel Facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

So I am examining the code of Laravel

I'm looking at the Storage facade. I think this is the way it's being loaded. Correct me if I am wrong.

- When ever we access the

  `Storage::get('someFile.txt');`
- The Storage is being accessed through the alias in the config am I correct?

  `'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class`
- It will then access the this function I believe

```html
protected static function getFacadeAccessor(){

  return 'filesystem';

}
```

- And then I think the return filesystem is accessing the filesystem stored on the service container I believe? This is set up in the FilesystemServiceProvider attaching to the container.

```html
protected function registerManager(){

  $this->app->singleton('filesystem', function () {
    return new FilesystemManager($this->app);
  });
}
```

So overall The Facade is referencing the filesystem on the service container am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is true: all the Facades in laravel are a only a convenient way to resolve objects from the Service Container and call methods on them

so, first you register a binding on the Service Container, and once you've done it, instead of doing

```
$fs = App::make('filesystem');
$file = $fs->get('someFile.txt');
```

you can simply do:

```
$file = Storage::get('someFile.txt');
```